# Why would this work in WAMP (offline) but not online?

Tags: php

I don't even know whats going on, this worked in my WAMP version, but when I transfered it to an online project for school it gives me this: "**Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object in /home/hogand5/public_html/bryson/view_adopt.php on line 7**"

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include("../connection/connect.php");
    $pokeId = $_SESSION['id'];

    $result = mysqli_query($con, "select * from eebb_pokemon where `id` = ".$pokeId."");
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();


    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

I'm trying to use that data to populate my HTML below:

```
<div id='slideWrap' style='position:relative; float:left; text-align:center;'>
    <img src="<?php echo $row['imageURL'];?>" height='200px'/><br/>
</div>
<div id='textSection' style='text-align:center;'>
    <h2><?php echo $row['name'];?></h2>
    <p>
        <?php echo $row['bio'];?>
    </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I've had issues with different php versions between wamp and web server.

Answer (score 2):

1. Check if your school's php has mysqli feature enabled or present

   echo phpinfo();
2. Check if you are really connected to the database

   var_dump($con);

Answer (score 0):

Maybe $result is not object. Try var_dump($result).